# Initialise a list element referring to an earlier element from the same list

Tags: python-3.x

Given the list

```
l = [ "ALPHA ONE", 123, _( "Alpha One" ), _( "ALPHA ONE" ) ]
```

where elements `2` and `3` (the translated text) are both tied directly to element `0`.

Is it possible to define the list in which elements `2` and `3` dynamically refer to element `0`?  Is there a notation/mechanism for a list element to be initialised by referring to an earlier element?

For example, something along the lines of

```
l = [ "ALPHA ONE", 123, _( [ 0 ].title() ), _( [ 0 ].upper() ) ]
```

This would make life easier/safer as I don't want to have to define essentially the text over and over.

Comment: Nope. Consider using a class with some properties (dynamically computed attributes) for this.

Comment: Tried both answers and whilst they both work in terms of displaying the text when I run my program, when I run gettext to produce the POT file, the text does not come through...unless I've missed something...

Comment: @Bernmeister What you're missing is that gettext only works with ***literal*** strings. If the original data is scraped from a webpage, how are you embedding the *literal* form of the first element of the list in your code? For this to work, somehow your code would have to look exactly like this: `[x := _("LITERAL TEXT"), 123, x.title(), x.upper()]`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, I've come to the conclusion that this is the case and suspect that although it is easy enough to define element 'n+1' with respect to element 'n', it's getttext that is now the snag.

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.8 this is possible using assignment expressions (the walrus operator). Assign the first element to a name using the walrus operator and then reuse this variable in the other elements

```
l = [(x := "ALPHA ONE"), 123, _(x.title()), _(x.upper())]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to put it in a `list` literal? Also, this seems more like a `tuple`.

```py
t = "ALPHA ONE"
l = (t, 123, _(t.title()), _(t.upper()))
```

Comment: The original data, `ALPHA ONE` and `123` are scraped from a webpage and there's about a 100.  No specific reason why I chose a list over a tuple.